# Error "Not allowed to connect to this database" C# MySQL

Tags: c#

I am getting an error that's something like "host is. It allowed to connect to this MySQL database" when I run my C# MySQL Connector/Net code to simply connect to the database. Anyone know how to fix this issue?

Comment: check if the mysql user exists and is granted to the database you try to connect to

Comment: share your connection string masking sensitive information and your code so that we can help

Comment: I think I may have a way to fix it. I believe there is a way to modify the allow settings in phpmyadmin. If I don't fix it, I'll return here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to manually allow your IP to access the database through the database control panel which is presumably on your hosting service's website.

Answer (score 0):

Manually allow your IP through your admin panel.